# why does this C++ STL code fail in compilation

Tags: c++

> Compilation error
>
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stream_iterator.h:199:13: error: no match for
>   ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream_iterator > >::ostream_type {aka
>   std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘const std::pair >’)

I failed in solving this.
I tried fixing this piece of code in many ways, changing the 
pairing way in map and pair

```
pair<int, string >
pair<int, string &>
pair<int, char *>
```

error prints are complex [for me] to digest

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
map<int, string> science {{101,"physics"},{102,"chemistry"}};

auto itrt = ostream_iterator<pair<int, string > >(cout, ",");

copy(science.begin(), science.end(),itrt);
return 1;
}
```

expected result: - 
**101 physics, 102 chemistry,**

Comment: I suspect you got much more than a single error. That is a side-effect of using the STL (spaghetti error message spew... that can be a bit difficult to nail down at first... It gets better)

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
ostream_iterator<pair<int, string > >
```

only if you define the following overload in your own code

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::pair<int, std::string> const& p);
```

The standard library does not provide such an overload.

To make it more general, you may overload:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::pair<T1, T2> const& p);
```

Comment: Or more generally `template <typename T1, typename T2> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::pair<T1, T2> const& p)`

Comment: @Caleth, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work...
(as copy and ostream_iterator does not work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
typedef std::pair<int ,string> PairII;

string to_s(PairII const & pii) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << pii.first << " " << pii.second ;
    return ss.str();
}
int main()
{
    map<int, string> science {{101,"physics"},{102,"chemistry"}};
    std::transform(science.begin(), science.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, " , "), to_s);

    return 0;
}
```